# My custom route does not work properly after login

Tags: reactjs

I have an application where i used routes. Also i created PrivateRoute for one page. According to my plan, the first page when i open the application should be Login page, after i click on `Login` button from Login component, i should be redirected to home page. 
Now  i set in localStorage a key to know when to be redirected, but it does not work, because even i add in localstoregae the key, i stay on Login page after clicking the button.

`<button onClick={() => localStorage.setItem("auth", true)}>Login</button>`.
My PrivateRoute looks like this:

```js
 <Route
      path={path}
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        localStorage.getItem("auth") ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login" }} />
        )
      }
    />
```

**Question**: How to do, when i will click on the login button  to be redirected to home page? And why, now, the condition:

```js
 localStorage.getItem("auth") ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login" }} />
        )
```

does not work?

 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-platform-26y3m?file=/src/Login.js:83-163

Answer (score 0):

Check this sandbox (a fork of yours): https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-galois-1e6sn

I'm passing the source path to Redirect component in PrivateRoute.js which I'm using in the Login component to redirect back once the user logs in.

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
<Route
  path={path}
  {...rest}
  render={props =>
    localStorage.getItem("auth") ? (
      <Component {...props} />
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login", callback: path }} />
    )
  }
/>
```

**Login.js**

```
export default function Login(props) {

  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(localStorage.getItem("auth"))

  const authorize = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("auth", true)
    setAuth(true)
  }

  return (
    auth
    ? <Redirect to={{ pathname: props.location.callback }}   />
    : <div><button onClick={() => authorize()}>Login</button></div>
  );
}
```